# Checking for overflow

Tags: arm, overflow

I'm currently attempting to check for signed overflow when a multiplication operation is conducted by using the following method...

```
muls r0, r1, r0
blvs overflow
```

Which would branch off and print an overflow error message if overflow occurred.  For example if the following input was r1 = 1,000,000,000 and r0 = 3 the output would be -64,771,072, but the branch to overflow is never done,  why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply that multiply instructions [will never set the overflow flag](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473l/dom1361289882394.html). `MULS` will only set the N and Z flags appropriately, and won't touch C or V (unless you're on something *truly* ancient where they get overwritten with meaningless nonsense).

If the significant bits of the result matter, you might want to consider using `UMULL`/`SMULL` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one bit to save overflow (another for carry) in ALU / APSR and those get set as a side effect of adding or subtracting arithmetic not because CPU realizes it will overflow. So in multiplication case those don't get set.

There is a nice blog post at ARM Connected Community titled [Detecting Overflow from MUL](https://community.arm.com/groups/processors/blog/2010/08/25/detecting-overflow-from-mul) which actually proposes how you can detect overflowing via some other means.